# import nested data into pandas from a json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a generated file as follows:

```
[{"intervals": [{"overwrites": 35588.4, "latency": 479.52}, {"overwrites": 150375.0, "latency": 441.1485001192274}], "uid": "23"}]
```

I simplified the file a bit for space reasons (there are more columns besides for the "overwrites" and "latency" ). I would like to import the data into a dataframe so I can later on draw the latency. I tried the following:

```
with open(os.path.join(path, "my_file.json")) as json_file:
   curr_list=json.load(json_file)   
    df=pd.Series(curr_list[0]['intervals'])

print df
```

which returned:

**0      {u'overwrites': 35588.4, u'latency...**

**1      {u'overwrites': 150375.0, u'latency...**

However I couldn't get to store df in a data structure that allows me to access the latency field as follows:

```
graph = df[['latency']]
graph.plot(title="latency")
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = [{"intervals": [{"overwrites": 35588.4, "latency": 479.52}, 
                       {"overwrites": 150375.0, "latency": 441.1485001192274}], 
         "uid": "23"}]


result = json_normalize(data, 'intervals', ['uid'])
print result
    latency  overwrites uid
0  479.5200     35588.4  23
1  441.1485    150375.0  23
```